# Android load activity from Fragment Tab

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi I am developing an app with 3 tabs. Once i click the 3rd tab I want to load an activity without the tabbar in it...how can i do it ?

```
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myview, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator(view),
                MyClass.class, null);
```

Comment: In your tab adapter you must have a method to track the click on the tabs. You can check "IF"  the current tab and instead of the usual stuff you must load a new activity that does not contain tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code. Here is [Complete Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/)

```
Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, MyClass.class);
TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHos.newTabSpec("tab3")
      .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_android_config))
      .setContent(intentAndroid);

mTabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);
```

Comment: Thanks Ketan for answering my question.. but i need to use framents for tabs, only the 3rd tab click i want to load as an activity(without the tab bar in it)

Comment: Why don't you use actionbar ?